# LLVM / iOS compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, llvm

I'm trying to link my iOS app with llvm/clang to run in iOS simulator.
I've added lib*.a to frameworks and still having unresolved symbols errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_del_curterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
  "_set_curterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
  "_setupterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
  "_tigetnum", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Does it mean it uses absent methods? How can i fix/walk-around it?

PS. After googling i've found that these methods relate to `term.h` lib which seems to be absent in iOS SDK.. What can i do?

Comment: I would guess needing term.h is for outputting color on the console etc - make sure you're not trying to put the command line front end code into your iOS app.

Comment: it seems that libLLVMSupport.a is pretty basic library and i have about 150 "unresolved symbols errors" without this file included in XCode project